# How to use a kaniko based gitlab-runner to build a node.js image?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, kaniko

I am using a self hosted Gitlab repository to push my code. The code contains a Dockerfile that successfully creates a docker-image locally on my machine. My intention is now to automate this build process and integrate the docker-build in a Gitlab-Pipeline. I am bound to shared runners, so I can't integrate my own runners. And those runners aren't set up for simple docker-in-docker builds. 
I saw another project who uses the image `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug` for this problem. It successfully starts the build process of my Dockerfile, but after executing my first `RUN` argument it starts to add millions of artifacts to the layer, till it freezes.

I tried to replace the node:latest image with node:slim and it went one execution further in the Dockerfile. So I think that the problem is within the loading of the base-image. But I can't make out the reason. 
Is Kaniko not able to download the base-image? 
Do I need to provide the base-image in a different way? 
Does someone have an example for a functioning kaniko pipeline that builds an image based on node?

Following part shows the logs of the runner.

```
<pre>
>Resolved base name node:latest to node:latest
>Downloading base image node:latest
>No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous
>Error while retrieving image from cache: getting file info: stat /cache   /sha256:a954de83ca1e2dfee3bdb4fedd56df42646f6325f50347482724626327b187c6: no such file or directory
>Downloading base image node:latest       
>No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous
>Built cross stage deps: map[]               
>Downloading base image node:latest          
>No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous
>Error while retrieving image from cache: getting file info: stat /cache
/sha256:a954de83ca1e2dfee3bdb4fedd56df42646f6325f50347482724626327b187c6: no such file or directory
>Downloading base image node:latest          
>No matching credentials were found, falling back on anonymous
>Unpacking rootfs as cmd RUN http_proxy=$proxy apt-get update &&     http_proxy=$proxy apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils build-essential libudev-dev && true requires it. 
>Taking snapshot of full filesystem...        
>Adding /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/mimetypes/tgz.png to layer, because it was changed. 
>Adding /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/actions/stock_select-all.png to layer, because it was changed. 
>...Continues with adding stuff till it freezes
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the kaniko executor's [debug image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#debug-image), which provides `sh` for gitlab-runner ci to execute

```
build:
  image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
  stage: build
  script:
    - executor --dockerfile=Dockerfile --context=$PWD --no-push
```

the reason for this is that if the image doesn’t allow to run scripts with `CMD`, the image will not work with the Docker executor. see ref [gitlab runner's docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-entrypoint)

For other `docker push`, you can follow the example to add extra configuration in your `.gitlab-ci.yaml`.